# Java round down including the next integer

Tags: java, int, rounding, divide

I'm curious about whether Java has a capability to round down from the next integer inclusive, e.g. 4 rounds down to 3, or 10 rounds down to 9.

For some context, I'm doing int divides, so my result will already be rounded down. 6/4 would round to 1, 7/4 would round to 1, but I want 8/4 which naturally rounds to 2 to instead round to 1. 9/4 would then round to 2, continuing to 12/4 rounding to 2.

Is there a function or code trick to achieve this?

Comment: I can't think of any method to do this automatically, but it's not hard to check if result*divisor is equal to dividend, and decrement it if it is.

Comment: That would work, I think.

Comment: To get a "correct" answer you will have to specify unambiguously what you want, i.e. give a mathematical rule that defines the output for every possible input.  Without that every possible answer is just a guess.  For example, what do you want for the result of `100/10`?  `9`? What about `101/10`?  Is that still `9` or is it `10`? What about `10001/10000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to achieve if you do a division anyhow. Just do `(a-1)/b` as integer division.

Answer (score 0):

This should be logically equivalent to subtracting one and then taking the ceiling of the result.